# Python Pivot 550+ Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, python-3.8

I have a dataframe with 558 columns in it. The first 12 columns are monthly sales, and the rest of the columns are characteristics of a product. Each row of the dataframe represents a single product.

I want to pivot the table so that the 12 sales columns for each product are representative rows for the product i.e. each product then will have 12 rows.

I thought the following code would work:

```
df.pivot(index=df[df.columns[0:11]] , columns=df[df.columns[12:558]])
```

But, no luck.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: sounds like you're trying to pivot an already pivoted dataframe, you need to `melt` try `pd.melt(df,id_vars=[df.iloc[:,:11]])` see what that gets you. better if you post a [mcve] so we can show a solution based on your data.

Comment: this is melt `df.melt(id_vars = [*df.columns[:11]])`

Comment: @Datanovice thanks a bunch! worked like a charm, just had to alter column selections a bit

Comment: @ansev also worked like a charm! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `df = df.melt(id_vars = [*df.columns[-546:]])`